# Does a low RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR affect performance after initial allocation?

Tags: ruby, performance, memory, memory-management

If I set `RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR` very low (say, 1.01) for my web app, will this affect performance after the initial boot of the server processes? Since ruby asks for OS memory and never gives it back, isn't this initial growth phase the only thing that is affected?

Answer (score 1):

`RUBY_GC_HEAP_GROWTH_FACTOR` determines how much extra memory is allocated if Ruby runs out of memory. If memory requirements were to spike suddenly in your app, such a low factor will slow down your responses significantly. If the number of requests you handle stays almost constant you could get away with such a low setting - but with 1% increases the "boot up time" of your app could take up to a few minutes during which performance will be abysmal. Allocating memory, especially in small chunks using a lot of syscalls can be very slow. It is up to you to decide if saving a few MB of memory will be worth it, but I'd tend to say no.

It's also worth nothing that Ruby *does* in fact free memory after use (with the exception of constants), although quite slowly.

Comment: "Ruby does in fact free memory after use" - intersting -- do you know where I can read about this?